# Proving that the normalization is independent of time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, integration, normalization

The function that I want to normalize represents an Airy wave-packet:
$$\psi(x,t)=\mathrm{Ai}[q(x-ut+ivt-\tfrac12at^2)]e^{i\frac{mat}{\hbar}(x-ut-\frac13at^2)}e^{\frac{mv}{\hbar}(x-ut+\frac i2vt-at^2)}e^{i\frac{mu}{\hbar}(x-\frac12ut)},$$
where $\mathrm{Ai}(...)$ is an Airy function. It is true that this function is a solution of the Schrödinger's equation, so the normalization should be independent of time. How can I prove it?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Airy wavepackets are not normalizable. What is it, precisely, that you want to calculate here?

Comment: What is q in the argument of the Airy function?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty this specific wavepacket is normalizable. Check this article (doi:10.1088/0143-0807/30/3/L04).

Comment: @GiorgioP q is a constant.

Comment: @jooanny Then it's inaccurate to call it "Airy wavepacket".

Answer (score 1):

The normalization of $|\psi\rangle$ remains true for all times $t$.

This can be be proven in full generality for any solution of Schrödinger's
time-dependent equation
$$i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle=H|\psi\rangle$$
or
$$\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle=-\frac{i}{\hbar}H|\psi\rangle.$$

The complex conjugate of this equation is
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi| &=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\psi|H^\dagger \\
&= \frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\psi|H
\end{align}$$
because the Hamiltonian is self-adjoint ($H^\dagger=H$).

Using these we can calculate the time derivative of $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|\psi\rangle
&= \left(\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|\right)|\psi\rangle
  +\langle\psi|\left(\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle\right) \\
&= \frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle
  -\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle\psi|H|\psi\rangle \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
That means $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle$ is independent of time $t$.

Comment: Yes, I know the general proof. However, I would like to prove that the normalization for this specific function is a constant number. I used Mathematica but I cannot figure it out.